# Return the indices of the k smallest values of a matrix in R

Tags: r, indexing, minimum

Suggest I have the following matrix in R:

```
set.seed(123)  # the only way to have a reproducible result
m <- matrix(runif(16,1,20), 8,1)

 m
          [,1]
[1,]  6.463973
[2,] 15.977798
[3,]  8.770562
[4,] 17.777331
[5,] 18.868878
[6,]  1.865573
[7,] 11.034004
[8,] 17.955962
```

I now wish to return the indices of the 4 smallest values in a sorted way. In that example I seek to obtain an object that contains the indices 6, 1, 3, 7 , sorted from the 1st smallest to the 4th smallest value. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to search the whole matrix or just one column at a time?

Comment: you are looking for `order(m)[1:4]`

Comment: `sapply(1:4, function(x) which(m == sort(m)[x]))`.

Comment: @Onyambu: Great, probably the shortest way of doing so!

Answer (score 0):

This function sort your matrix elements in ascending order. The option index.return set to TRUE will add the indexes in addition to the sorted value. $ix allows you to directly return the sorted indexes

```
sort(m,index.return = TRUE)$ix
```